# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use a RecyclerView and I added the line `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'` to my `build.gradle (app)` but it gives the error `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1` I have seen other answers suggest adding

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

to the `build.gradle` file but it was already in there and has not helped. All my SDK tools are installed and up to date.

**build.gradle(Project):**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '1.1.1'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
}
```

**build.gradle(App):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.findmyitem"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Try this `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'` and `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because there is no *28.1.1* version. The latest one is *28.0.0* so use that. Add this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

instead of:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1'
```

You can check the latest version or all the versions ever released [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/recyclerview-v7?repo=google)

**Update:**

Android is moving away from **Android AppCompat Library** to **Androidx**.
Going forward you should ideally use these libraries as all the new updates will be for them. To use it include

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

and instead of

`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1'`

use

`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'`

for recyclerview.

Again, You can check the latest version or all the versions ever released of Androidx Appcompat [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.recyclerview/recyclerview)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1'`

update it to

`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`

Latest one is 28.0.0

**Most probably 28.0.0 might be the last version of the old support libraries, after that migrate your existing project to AndroidX.**

AndroidX provides all the features of the support libraries, in a collection of independently versioned libraries. Google can now release a new version of one component, without having to update the entire support library.