# I am getting red line while using this dependency in android studio. How to resolve this?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-recyclerview

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

When I add this dependency, I got red line error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984511/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportrecyclerview-v728-1-1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to migrate to AndroidX. In your Android Studio project click Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX (all implementations will be replaced from android.support to androidx).

Answer (score 1):

This component is by default available in `Palette`. Check it in Palette as below image

**Solution -1**

[image]

If you are not able to use it then you have to download it first. Sometimes developers have to download this before use. Just click on [image] download button to use.

**Solution -2**

use this dependency [For AndroidX]

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
```